# Send a message back to user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

When I send some data in the database and the text is successful, it should be notified and if there is an error, it should give a mistake.

The message must be displayed on Create or Login, but it depends on whether it is succe or error.

```
AccountViews model = new AccountViews();
var mail = model.Email;
var result = _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Brugernavn == mail);
if(result == null)
{

    model.Message = "Succes";

    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}

model.Message = "Error";

return RedirectToAction("Create");
```

In my model I have:

```
[TempData]
public string Message { get; set; }
public bool ShowMessage => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Message);
```

Then **the question** here is how can I get my message to appear?

The problem is, as I see it, that how I get my message to appear on the page when I send me / someone over to another page.

I work in MVC - .Net core 2.0

Comment: https://youtu.be/yyBijyCI5Sk?t=37m12s @mjwills u can see here what i try to make.

Comment: @mjwills, i `overlooked` the `Redirect` part of the `code`. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass it using query string like this:

```
RedirectToAction("Create", new { error= "ErrorMsg" });
```

So to get this in your destination Action you should add an argument to your create action:

```
public ActionResult Create(string error){
//do what you want with error
//to show this in view you can use viewbag like:
ViewBag.Error = error;
return View();
}
```

then you can show it as easy as call it in your Create view file like:

```
<div> @ViewBag.Error <div>
```